# Load view with onclick event

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following view [image]

Which is genererated from javascript:

```
//Zητάει τις κατηγορίες από την βάση
    var appendCategoreis = function(categories){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/perouka/index.php/MainController/getCategories",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data,function(item){
                var node = $(categories);

                node.find(".category-title").html(data[item].Name);
                node.find(".category-icon").css({"background-image":"url("+data[item].Icon+")"});
                node.attr("onclick","window.location.href='http://localhost/perouka2/perouka/index.php/ResultsController/loadView'");
                $(".categories").append(node);


            });
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
    }

    //Φορτώνει το template για της κατηγορίες
    $.get( "application/views/templates/category.html", appendCategoreis);
```

The important line is `node.attr("onclick","window.location.href='http://localhost/perouka2/perouka/index.php/ResultsController/loadView'");`where I add an onlick event on each of these categories. This calls my controller:

```
class ResultsController extends CI_Controller
{


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function loadView(){
        $this->load->view('navbar');
    }

}
```

When I run the above and click on one I am getting a `FileError: 'http://localhost/perouka2/perouka/index.php/ResultsController/css/navbar.less' wasn't found (404)`

What is the best practise for loading views on onclick events?

Comment: is there a method call css in the resultscontroller coz according to the error there must be method called css. So check ur controller.

Comment: @Nyaro my question is not about the error, I know what causes the error, css is not a method is a directory upper in the structure of my application.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return view as data, like:

```
...
public function loadView(){
   echo $this->load->view('navbar', '', true);
}
...
```

and use [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), as:

```
$( "#your_element" ).load( "http://localhost/perouka2/perouka/index.php/ResultsController/loadView", function() {
   console.log( "view loaded." );
});
```

Comment: returning it as data is not necessary. You can simple use `$this->load->view('blah');`